# Selenium : Handling modal dialog box

Tags: java, selenium, modal-dialog, alert

```
driver.get("https://www.leafground.com/alert.xhtml");
        //Alert simple
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt91")).click();
        
        Alert alert1 = driver.switchTo().alert();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        alert1.accept();
        
        //Alert confirm
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt93")).click();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        Alert alert2 = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert2.accept();
        
        //Prompt dialog
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt104")).click();
        Thread.sleep(500);
        Alert alert3 = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert3.sendKeys("Praveen Sundaram");
        alert3.dismiss();
        
        // sweet alert 
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt95")).click();
        String s = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-dialog-titlebar")).getText();
        System.out.println(s);
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt98")).click();
        
        //Sweet alert confirmation
        
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt106")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt108")).click();
        
        
        //modal
        driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt100")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]")).click();
```

Everything passes except the last modal dialog box. It has only 'X' button to close the box. I was able to locate the element but when I perform click operation. it is not closing the box. I even checked whether the 'x' is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to consider here.

1. You need to wait for `model popup` to appear, you can user either `implicit wait` or `explicit wait` or `sleep` method.
2. absolute `xpath` is always fragile, always try to use relative `xpath` to uniquely identify the element.

code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt88:j_idt100")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='j_idt88:j_idt101']//span[@class='ui-icon ui-icon-closethick']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks brother!! it worked. Seemed like the wait was the problem. I added a sleep of 1000 second as per your code and it worked.